# How to make ssl server certificate created by a private CA trusted?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests, ca

I have created a private CA in Ubuntu and issued a ssl server certificate by this CA. When I enabled https web service with the ssl certificate, the certificate issued by the CA is still not trusted.

Firstly I typed the command to create the private CA:

```
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newca
```

Then, I created a certificate by these commands:

```
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newreq
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -sign
```

Finally, I configured the web service with the ssl certificate. From the web browser, I could see the newly generated certificate which, however is not trusted by the browser.

Then, I tried to write code to make https request on the same host where the private CA sits.

```
requests.get('https://IP:PORT/res', verify=True)
```

Unfortunately, I got ssl exception as below:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

**The questions is how to make the cert created by the private CA trusted. Thanks**

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: @KenWhite, it is about coding. I have made the question more concrete.

Comment: It is not about coding. The private CA's certificate must be present in the trusted certificates of the client as configured in the OpenSSL configuration. You don't have to do anything with each specific signed certificate.

Comment: @EJP I can understand the logical mechanism. But I just don't know how to make the private CA system-wide trusted as the server and client are on the same host. Or to make it code-wide trusted by passing some parameters to the requests module.

Comment: You have to configure it in the OpenSSL configuration. This is not the place to merely reiterate existing documentation.